# How to dynamic package name for android library project in different flavor

Tags: android

I have two flavor in android library project, i want to change the package name for different one, the library project have AndroidManifest.xml for each flavor, but the package attribute can't be change in mainfest, do any one knows how to change in build process?

Answer (score 2):

You can define different package name for each flavor as following.
Inside your build.gradle

```
android{
 .....
  signingConfigs {

    configFlavor1{
        keyAlias 'abc'
        keyPassword 'abc@123'
        storeFile file('abc.jks')
        storePassword 'abc@123'
    }
   configFlavor2{
        keyAlias 'abc2'
        keyPassword 'abc2@123'
        storeFile file('abc2.jks')
        storePassword 'abc2@123'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId 'com.abc.cde'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 10
        dimension "default"
        versionName "1.0.0.0"
    }

    flavor2 {
        applicationId 'com.abc.efg'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 10
        dimension "default"
        versionName "1.0.0.0"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFlavor1
        productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFlavor2
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but my case is android library project which not support applicationId